# convertir horas y minutos a decimales

Tags: vb.net

estoy haciendo un calculo en horas tengo 3300 minutos lo que representan 55:00 hrs, mediante la siguiente linea puedo convertir los 3300 en horas:

```
Dim totalMinutos As Integer = 3300
    Dim minutos As Integer = 0
    Dim horas As Integer = Math.DivRem(totalMinutos, 60, minutos)
    Label13.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", horas, minutos)
```

en el label me aparecen 55:00
ahora bien mi pregunta es como convertir esas 55:00 hrs de nuevo en 3300

gracias. estoy usando visual basic 2010

Comment: quizá 55 * 60 te de el resultado

Comment: eso seria lo mas obvio, la cosa es que al convertirlo del label se pasa como string "55:00" y alli viene el problema al quererlo multiplicar

Comment: bueno buscá como se usa Convert.toInt32

Comment: no es de mucha ayuda tu respuesta, pero gracias.

Comment: evidentemente has copiado el código, no te lo voy a hacer, que no te sea útil no siginifica que no sea correcta.

Comment: Ya consegui lo que necesitaba, me supongo que eres como el otro que no estan dispuestos a ayudar, sino andan buscando a quien cobrarle, es mas nisiquera creo que supieras la respuesta ya que no conveti en ningun momento a int32. tal vez no sea el codigo mas bonito pero funciono.

Answer (score 2):

Ahora tienes un texto. este lo puedes separar usando la función Split en un arreglo.
El índice 0 del arreglo, lo conviertes en entero y lo multiplicas por 60, luego le sumas la conversión a entero del índice 1.

```
Dim totalMinutos As Integer = 3300
Dim minutos As Integer = 0
Dim horas As Integer = Math.DivRem(totalMinutos, 60, minutos)
Label13.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", horas, minutos)

Dim splitHora() As String
splitHora = Split(Label13.Text, ":")
minutos = Int(splitHora(0)) * 60 + Int(splitHora(1))
Label14.Text = minutos
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo un label y un datetimepicker en formato HH:mm, al colocar una hora automaticamente me actualiza el label restandole las horas

```
Dim th1, th2 As String
        Dim TB1(), tb2() As String
        Dim Resu1, resu2 As Single
        'calculamos las horas disponibles
        th1 = tior
        TB1 = Split(th1, ":")

        Resu1 = TB1(0) + ((TB1(1) * 100) / 60) / 100
        Dim tie1 As Double = Resu1 * 60
        'calculamos las horas dispuestas
        th2 = DateTimePicker1.Text
        tb2 = Split(th2, ":")

        resu2 = tb2(0) + ((tb2(1) * 100) / 60) / 100
        Dim tie2 As Double = resu2 * 60
        Dim resto As Double = Resu1 - resu2
        'colocar en el label
        Dim totalMinutos As Integer = resto * 60
        Dim minutos As Integer = 0
        Dim horas As Integer = Math.DivRem(totalMinutos, 60, minutos)
        Label13.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", horas, minutos)
```